# Delete tomcat logs after N days or week

Tags: logging, tomcat7

I want to clean log files on tomcat/logs/ folder which are older than 7 days. Log rotation is working and new logs are generated every day. I prefer not to use any external scripts. Is it possible to configure log deletion through tomcat/conf/logging.properties? Please advise.